# How do I query for a measure as a single calculated value (10 days average) and not separated by granularity (daily measure)?

Tags: javascript, analytics, cube.js

I have a doubt. I currently have a cube with a *preAggregation* defined with day granularity and some measures `A, B, C`. 
The *preAggregation* works fine when I query using `timeDimension` with a fixed `dateRange` and `granularity` (it retrieves a time series that I can plot in a chart, so everything is ok to this point).

My problem is that I also want to show these measures (`A, B, C`) averaged as a single value, but if I remove the `granularity` from the `timeDimension`, the cube stops using the *preAggregation*, and instead it performs the full query.

Summarizing:
I need a to retrieve a `measure` (such as sales $$$) for each day of a fixed time range (separated as a series), and I also need the monthly average (as a single number). How do I build the second query (single value `measure`)? For the first one, I simply add the following `timeDimension`:

```js
{
   "granularity": "day",
   "dimension": "timestamp",
   "dateRange": [
      "2020-01-26T00:00:00Z",
      "2020-02-06T00:00:00Z"
   ]
}
```

But when I want the measure aggregated for the same `dateRange` as a single value, I don't know how to build the query.

Answer (score 3):

All `avg` measures are considered **Not Additive** and it's why most of rollups that works for **Additive** ones aren't selected for queries containing `avg` measures: https://cube.dev/docs/pre-aggregations#rollup-rollup-selection-rules.

However there's a trick for average measures that allows to reclassify **Not Additive** measures to **Leaf Measure Additive**. For example you can rewrite

```js
cube(`Cube`, {
  // ...

  measures: {
    averageA: {
      // ...
      type: `avg`
    },

    averageB: {
      // ...
      type: `avg`
    },

    // ...

  },

  // ...

  preAggregations: {
    averagesRollup: {
      type: `rollup`
      measureReferences: [averageA, averageB, averageC],
      timeDimensionReference: timestamp,
      granularity: `day`
    }
  }
})
```

to:

```js
cube(`Cube`, {
  // ...

  measures: {
    A: {
      // ...
    },

    B: {
      // ...
    },

    // ...

    count: {
      type: `count`
    },

    averageA: {
      sql: `${A} / ${count}`,
      type: `number`
    },

    averageB: {
      sql: `${B} / ${count}`,
      type: `number`
    },
    // ...
  },

  // ...

  preAggregations: {
    averagesRollup: {
      type: `rollup`
      measureReferences: [A, B, C, count],
      timeDimensionReference: timestamp,
      granularity: `day`
    }
  }
})
```

In this case Cube.js knows that `averageA`, `averageB` and `averageC` measures are composed out of `A`, `B`, `C` and `count` and will use `averagesRollup` as in **Leaf Measure Additive** query and return results even if time dimensions granularity isn't set.

Comment: Pavel, thank you very much!
I still have a doubt: for example, the averageB measure states "B / count", but should it be something like "sum(B) / count"? or the B measure needs to be of type "sum"??

Comment: Measure B needs to be of some additive type like `sum`. Otherwise it won't be used either.